# How do I follow a Javascript Link without onClick

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, webbrowser-control, visual-c#-express-2010

This is my first time posting. I've been working on a "web scraper" to navigate through a website and download an Excel File or .CSV file automatically.

I'm running into a problem when I want to download the file. Here is the HTML:

`<"a class="PSQRYRESULTSTITLE" href="javascript: bSubmitted=false;submitAction_win2(document.win2,'#ICQryDownloadRaw');">CSV Text File<"/a>`

When clicked it opens a download prompt to save.

1. How do I trigger this prompt?
2. Can I bypass the prompt so it downloads automatically?

I'm coding this in Visual Studio C# 2008. I am using a WebBrowser Control to navigate through the website.

I've tried everything from 
`webbrowser1.document.invokescript`
to
storing all the elements in an HtmlElementCollection traversing through them and doing
invokemember("click")...

Nothing is working! Please help!

Comment: I think your use case sounds a lot like what the `wget` utility already does well. Have you looked at that?

Comment: haha this is actually what im looking for.. thanks! but i'm trying to program it myself ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (HtmlElement i in webBrowser1.Document.All)
    {
        if (i.OuterText == "CSV Text File" && i.GetAttribute("href") != "")
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(i.GetAttribute("href"));
        }
    }
```

although this doesn't answer my second question of how to automatically download the file or disable the prompt it got me moving forward finally. But if anyone has an answer for that it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. try invokescript eval with a string parameter of value `"javascript: bSubmitted=false;submitAction_win2(document.win2,'#ICQryDownloadRaw');"`
2. you can make an educated guess of the url and use `UrlDownloadToFile` to download it to your location, or make another web request to download the file if `UrlDownloadToFile` fails.

Comment: I tried both but found a different way to get it to work. Thank you though!